# How to use templateUrl in Angular 2 directive

Tags: angular2-directives

How do I add a html template to a directive? Here is a sample code which does not work :

> import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
>
> @Directive({
>   selector: '[master-side-bar]',
>   templateUrl :
>   'master-side-bar.html' })
>
> export class MasterSideBar {
>
> constructor() {
>
> ```
> console.log('Hello MasterSideBar Directive');
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

I get the following error :

> Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; }' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'Directive'. Object literal may only
>   specify known properties, and 'templateUrl' does not exist in type
>   'Directive'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your code, you need to use **component** not directives.

Component is the only directive which accepts template as HTML.

Please check [Types of directives](https://www.codementor.io/christiannwamba/build-custom-directives-in-angular-2-jlqrk7dpw)

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out component. I changed to use component instead and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

According to Angular docs there are 2 types of directives: attribute and structural. None of them support templates. Just use angular Component. Is there some good reason that you want to use directive necessarily?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out component. I am pretty new to Angular 2. I changed to use component instead and it worked.